# Story about a candidate who fails an audition because they were volunteering the previous day

Tags: identification-request

Does anyone recognize this story? I think I read it some ~15? years ago and it's probably a classic of some kind, since it was translated. I don't remember the original language, but it was probably a short story.

There is an audition for [singing role]. One of the candidates at the audition performs remarkably, such that the committee feels that if they're going to accept anyone at all, they would accept this candidate. However the audition is 2-legged, and there's still a second audition. At the second audition, the candidate performs terribly and leaves with an apologetic smile. A member of the committee feels something must be wrong, so they investigate; they discover that the candidate was doing some kind of charity work the previous day & night such that they'd gotten no rest and their voice had become hoarse, explaining the poor performance.

I'm relatively confident the candidate is female, but don't remember anything else.

I skimmed through a copy of [*Heart*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_(novel)) and it looks like the story is not from the novel.

Comment: Hi @Allure, and welcome to LitSE. There's already lots of good details in this question, but can you have a scan of the [story identification suggested questions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and see if there's anything else you can add?